# What is the use of {0} in c# console.writeline?

Tags: asp.net

What is the use of {0} in the 
console.writeline("Length: {0]");
in c#.
and why are we using it?

Answer (score 7):

`{0}` is a format string parameter.

For example,

```
    Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}!", "World")
```

will output

```
    Hello World!
```

to the Console.

Note, that in your example, the code reads `{0]` instead of `{0}` and you are also missing an argument for the intended parameter.  In my example, the string `"World"` is the argument for the `{0}` format parameter).

A good, introductory source of information for this is available at: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/StringFormat.aspx .  It is worth noting that

```
    Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}!", "World");
```

is equivalent to

```
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hello {0}!", "World"));
```